# Click the first element of the array found from xpath in web-driver

Tags: jmeter

Through web driver sampler I am getting 3 elements for the element contain a text, and I want to click the first element. How to achieve this ?

Code in Web Driver Sampler,

```
var waitPKG = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var wait = new waitPKG.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);


wait.until(waitPKG.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'LeeTest')]")));
```

Dom Structure:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [findElement() function description:](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By))

> Find **the first WebElement** using the given method.

Just add `.click()` to the end of the last line of your code.

```
wait.until(waitPKG.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'LeeTest')]"))).click();
```

Also be informed [that the recommended language for scripting since JMeter 3.1 is Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it might be worth considering migrating. More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Dmitri, just awesome